# Bottom navigator not switching tabs in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native

Okay so I am new to React Native so I believe that I just have a structural issue but I can not seem to realize what I am doing wrong.

I am trying to have 4 tabs but when I click on each tab it is not bringing me to the next page. So on each click of a tab nothing happens. What am I not understanding about this?

My files are as follows:

**App.tsx**

```
export default function App() {
  const isLoadingComplete = useCachedResources();
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  let [fontsLoaded, error] = useFonts({
    CormorantGaramond_300Light,
    CormorantGaramond_300Light_Italic,
    CormorantGaramond_400Regular,
    CormorantGaramond_400Regular_Italic,
    CormorantGaramond_500Medium,
    CormorantGaramond_500Medium_Italic,
    CormorantGaramond_600SemiBold,
    CormorantGaramond_600SemiBold_Italic,
    CormorantGaramond_700Bold,
    CormorantGaramond_700Bold_Italic
  });

  if (!isLoadingComplete) {
    return null;
  } else if (!fontsLoaded){
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {
    return (
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <Navigation colorScheme={colorScheme} />
        <StatusBar style="dark" />
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

**index.tsx**

```
export default function Navigation({ colorScheme }: { colorScheme: ColorSchemeName }) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      linking={LinkingConfiguration}
      >
      <RootNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

// A root stack navigator is often used for displaying modals on top of all other content
// Read more here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal
const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

function RootNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
      <Stack.Screen name="NotFound" component={NotFoundScreen} options={{ title: 'Oops!' }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

**BottomTabNavigator.tsx**

```
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator<BottomTabParamList>();

export default function BottomTabNavigator() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Meditation"
      tabBarOptions={{ activeTintColor: "#D3AAE2", activeBackgroundColor: "white", inactiveBackgroundColor: "white" }}>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Yoga"
        component={TabOneNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <MaterialCommunityIcons name="yoga" size={24} color={color}/>,
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name={"Meditation"}
        component={TabTwoNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <Ionicons name="planet" size={24} color={color} />,
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Food"
        component={TabThreeNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <MaterialCommunityIcons name="fruit-pineapple" size={24} color={color} />,
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={TabFourNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <MaterialIcons name="face" size={24} color={color} />,
        }}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}

// You can explore the built-in icon families and icons on the web at:
// https://icons.expo.fyi/
function TabBarIcon(props: { name: React.ComponentProps<typeof Ionicons>['name']; color: string }) {
  return <Ionicons size={30} style={{ marginBottom: -3 }} {...props} />;
}

// Each tab has its own navigation stack, you can read more about this pattern here:
// https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation#a-stack-navigator-for-each-tab
const TabOneStack = createStackNavigator<TabOneParamList>();

function TabOneNavigator() {
  return (
    <TabOneStack.Navigator>
      <TabOneStack.Screen
        name="Yoga"
        component={TabOneScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </TabOneStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const TabTwoStack = createStackNavigator<TabTwoParamList>();

function TabTwoNavigator() {
  return (
    <TabTwoStack.Navigator>
      <TabTwoStack.Screen
        name="Meditation"
        component={TabTwoScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </TabTwoStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const TabThreeStack = createStackNavigator<TabThreeParamList>();

function TabThreeNavigator() {
  return (
    <TabThreeStack.Navigator>
      <TabThreeStack.Screen
        name="Food"
        component={TabThreeScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </TabThreeStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const TabFourStack = createStackNavigator<TabFourParamList>();

function TabFourNavigator() {
  return (
    <TabFourStack.Navigator>
      <TabFourStack.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={TabFourScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </TabFourStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

**TabOneScreen.tsx** - all screen pages look like this with different numbers of course

```
export default function TabOneScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Tab One</Text>
      <View style={styles.separator} lightColor="#eee" darkColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.1)" />
      <EditScreenInfo path="/screens/TabOneScreen.tsx" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

**types.tsx**

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Root: undefined;
  NotFound: undefined;
};

export type BottomTabParamList = {
  Yoga: undefined;
  Meditation: undefined;
  Food: undefined;
  Profile: undefined;
};

export type TabOneParamList = {
  Yoga: undefined;
};

export type TabTwoParamList = {
  Meditation: undefined;
};

export type TabThreeParamList = {
  Food: undefined;
};

export type TabFourParamList = {
  Profile: undefined;
};
```

**LinkingConfiguration**

```
export default {
  prefixes: [Linking.makeUrl('/')],
  config: {
    screens: {
      Root: {
        screens: {
          Yoga: {
            screens: {
              TabOneScreen: 'one',
            },
          },
          Meditation: {
            screens: {
              TabTwoScreen: 'two',
            },
          },
          Food: {
            screens: {
              TabThreeScreen: 'three',
            },
          },
          Profile: {
            screens: {
              TabFourScreen: 'four',
            },
          },
        },
      },
      NotFound: '*',
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

hello can you provide the full BottomTabNavigator.tsx

you should have something like

```
import TabOneScreen from "../screens/TabOneScreen";
import TabTwoScreen from "../screens/TabTwoScreen";
...
```

and then in you TabOneScreen

```
const TabOneScreen = (props: Props) => {

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 16 }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
          }}>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 20,
              textAlign: 'center',
              marginBottom: 16,
            }}>
            Example of Splash, Login and Sigdsdn Up in React Native
            {'\n\n'}
            This is the Home Screen
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default TabOneScreen;
```

if you need more help i'm here